# How can a non-licensed user interact with CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I would like to build an event ticketing system in CRM 2011. The general idea is that CRM users and non-users alike need to be able to submit ticket requests for sporting events, which are then stored in an entity and eventually approved. Some people will get tickets and some won't, so not all the requests actually turn into tickets.

It needs to be accessible even to users who are on the network but don't necessarily have CRM. The trouble I am having is determining how I should let non-users create ticket requests.

One possible solution would be to e-mail everybody when an event opens and allow them to send back a reply e-mail with information like their name and the number of tickets they want, and parse the results with a plug in with the DeliverIncoming message. I think that would work, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it.

Would it be possible to build a webpage and somehow communicate with the CRM server to create a ticket request, even if the person doing so is not a CRM user?

EDIT:

In my case, the users are within the same organization, so the external connector license wouldn't work. And I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve buying several hundred limited access licenses for users that will only use CRM for tickets. Would it be possible to create, say, a .NET application which runs as a CRM user and handles the creation of the tickets? Or is there some functionality I could take advantage of on the CRM server to just route requests to a .NET application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be pretty easy to have an external system (simple .Net app) that collects the new tickets and "synchronizes" them to CRM with a tool like Scribe/CozyRoc.

I'm not sure if this type of "system-to-system" integration would permit standard licensing however.  I have heard of Microsoft give very good deals on ESS CALs and/or granting permitted use for similar situations.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely build a website to interact with CRM.

An example is the Customer Portal, you can find here:

http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-us/applications/customer-portal-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-12884910826

But for your purpose is a bit oversized. However the basic idea is the following:

You need to store the credentials (username and password) inside the contact entity or another entity that will map the users of your website, the website will run under a "service" user that will create reservations and tickets.

In this way you need only one CRM user but you can infinite website users

Comment: For this scenario you will need the external connector license